# Chamada de função dentro de ModalBox

Tags: javascript

Minha idéia é a seguinte, estou abrindo uma imagem em uma modalBox ( ou imagem Box, perdoe falar algo incorreto pois sou iniciante no assunto) em javascript, como faço pra chamar a função de zoom após chamar a função da modal box?

Obrigado.

Abaixo está o código que estou usando:

rodando aqui

```
<span class='zoom' id='ex3'>
   <img id="myImg" src="img/map1.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">
   <p>Hover</p>
</span>


<div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <span class="close">&times;</span>
   <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
   <div id="caption"></div> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
var
img.onclick = function(){
   modal.style.display = "block";
   modalImg.src = this.src;
   captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
   modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

E esta é a função que quero chamar:

fala que voce quer essa função : //Função do Zoom

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ex3').zoom({ on:'click' });
});
```

//Fim da Função

Comment: Queira postar o código que já tentou, e os erros que sucederam, no seu post.

Comment: MoshMage editei a pergunta e adicionei os codigos

Comment: Sim estou usando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema no  teu código é que estás a chamar o plugin `zoom` mal: [a documentação](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/) diz que tens que adicionar o "evento" zoom a um elemento *que não uma img tag*

Então, trocando o teu html da modal para:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <span class="close">&times;</span>
   <div class="zoom"><img class="modal-content" id="img01"></div>
   <div id="caption"></div> 
</div>
```

E mudando a tua função de `onclick` para:

```
img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    $('.zoom').zoom({
      on: 'click',
      url: this.src
    });
  }
```

A imagem [passa a fazer zoom](https://jsfiddle.net/ukjgghvt/)

Comment: Deu certo!! Muito obrigado